# Sampling in each region according to a segmentation map in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, sample

I want to sample a certain number of points in each region of the image according to a segment map(like what the SLIC algorithm produces, it's a map with the same size as the image, containing integers from 0 to num_segment indicating which segment each pixel belongs to).

Currently, I write my own code as follows:

- For `i` in range(0, num_segment):

  - find the (indexes of the)pixels that belong to the `i`th segment using `torch.where`
  - picking out those pixels and forming a 1-d tensor
  - use `torch.Upsample` to uniformly sample n_sample points for the `i`th segment
- stack all the sampled points to form a large 2-d tensor which each row represent selected points belong to one segment, and it has n_sample rows.

I not only want the original value from the image for each selected point, but their indexes are also needed.

I drew a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUHWV.png) to illustrate.

So, my question is, is there a native way to implement this in PyTorch? The above code runs a little bit slow, maybe the For-loop slows down the speed. And if possible, since all the sampling process are independent of each other, how can I speed up the process?

Generally, I have ~400 segments, and I want to sample 20~50 points for each segment.